# How to set split normals in edit mode python

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, bmesh

I'm making a function similar to the normal editing function Point to Target. When I run the following code, the split normals are changed from the first to the second image, but once I switch back to Object mode the split normals reset back to the first image. How can I correctly set the split normals so that they save when I switch back to Object mode? I'd like to set the split normals in edit mode so that I can see the split normal lines change as I change a reference point, similar to Point to Target.

```
import bpy
import bmesh

me = bpy.context.edit_object.data
me.use_auto_smooth = True
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
for f in bm.faces:
    for l in f.loops:
        l.face.normal = [1, 0, 0]
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
bm.free()
```

[image: default split normals]

[image: desired split normals]